# Should I use Firebase Dynamic Links over Universal and App Links?

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links, android-app-links

Im building an app for iOS and Android and need to open urls in the app on mobile and in the browser on desktop.
All links should open in the app if possible, so I cant generate one link for each possible url.

Can I do this in Firebase or do I have to create links in advance?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this question is related specifically to Firebase, or a general one.
I can try answering about the general case:

For opening in App:
In order to use Universal Links in iOS and AppLinks in Android, you'll need your click server to host Apple's AASA file or Android's asset file. This means that you'll need to serve that file for the operating system.

For opening in browser on desktop:
You'll need your click server to be able to detect desktop user agent and redirect you to store.

I didn't understand your question about: `All links should open in the app if possible, so I cant generate one link for each possible url.` Actually one link can fit all use cases, but you'll need to develop that capability in your own click server.